# How to create an Excel file and write VBA code in module using Python win32com?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Objective: To create an Excel file and write VBA code in an Excel module using Python win32com.

Problem: I use this code in Anaconda (Jupiter Notebook) without error. When I execute the code as .py format it is coming up with an error.

Python Code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

import comtypes, comtypes.client

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

xl.Visible = True

ss = xl.Workbooks.Add()

sh = ss.ActiveSheet

xlmodule = ss.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)  # vbext_ct_StdModule

sCode = '''sub VBAMacro()
       msgbox "VBA Macro called"
      end sub'''

xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: I'd expected this to work.  My guess is this errors because you traverse into a different type library.  You stop interacting with the Excel object library and start interacting with the VBA type library.

Comment: How to change the library to the VBA type library?